# Get exact scroll position with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, onscroll

I have 2 containers that I am trying to hijack the scroll event for and use translate to move them.  The first wraps the entire page and the second I want to scroll horizontally.

The issue is that I cannot get the exact scroll position when scrolling.  This results in the horizontal scrolling section never returning to 0 position when scrolling back up.

I realize this is probably the browser not returning every value that the scrollbar hits.

My question is how would you return the value of my horizontal scrolling container to 0 when scrolling back up? These values can be off considerably.  When scrolling fast it can be off 100px which is unnaceptable.

In the demo below I am console logging the scroll value in the `updateSection()` function.  This is a simple function that checks to see if the section is at the top of the viewport and then starts the horizontal scroll.  You can clearly see by the logs that when scrolling back up the translate value never gets back to 0.

Is there a good way to handle this and how do I get the exact number needed?

Here is a fiddle [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/uv31e28g/)

Here is a snippet

```js
const ScrollEase = opts => {
  const scrollContainer = document.querySelector(opts.container);
  const spacer = document.querySelector(opts.spacer);
  const containerOffset = opts.containerOffset || '0px';
  let yScroll = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;

  /**
   * ---------------------------------------------------------------
   * Styling Functions
   * ---------------------------------------------------------------
   */
  const setTransform = (el, transform) => {
    el.style.transform = transform;
    el.style.WebkitTransform = transform;
  };

  const setSpacerStyle = () => {
    const containerHeight = scrollContainer.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    const height = containerHeight;
    spacer.style.height = height + 'px';
    spacer.style.width = '1px';
    spacer.style.position = 'relative';
  };

  const setContainerStyle = () => {
    const top = containerOffset;
    scrollContainer.style.position = 'fixed';
    scrollContainer.style.top = top;
    scrollContainer.style.left = 0;
    scrollContainer.style.zIndex = 2;
    scrollContainer.style.width = '100%';
  };

  /**
   * ---------------------------------------------------------------
   * Animating Container Functions
   * ---------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  const updateScroll = () => {
    yScroll = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
    setTransform(scrollContainer, 'translateY(' + -yScroll + 'px)');
    updateSection();
  };

  const updateSection = () => {
    const el = document.querySelector('[data-type="scroll"]');
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    const bodyTop = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const offset = rect.top - bodyTop;

    if (rect.top < 0) {
      console.log(yScroll - offset);
      setTransform(el, 'translateX(' + -(yScroll - offset) + 'px)');
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener('scroll', updateScroll);
  setContainerStyle();
  setSpacerStyle();
};

ScrollEase({
  container: '.scrollContainer',
  spacer: '.scrollSpacer'
});
```

```css
[data-type='scroll'] {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 200vw;
  display: flex;
}

[data-type='scroll'] .box {
  flex: 1;
  background: rgb(200,200,200);
  margin: 2rem
}

footer{
  padding: 100px 10px;
  text-align:center;
  background: blue;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollSpacer"></div>
<div class="scrollContainer">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <div style="height: 100vh"></div>

  <div data-type="scroll">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 200vh"></div>

  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Any help or insights would be appreciated.